# How can I eliminate a duplicate record from a query based on the max timestamp of another column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duplicates

I used row number to identify these two rows, which are duplicate, the only column that is different is the last_modified.
[duplicate records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqebw.png).

How can I select only the one with the max last_modified date? (that is, the first line in yellow?)

I don't want to filter by the row_number results because it happens often in the source, I want to
I'm using Big Query SQL, by the way. :)

Thanks in advance for your help!

What I tried:

I did something like this:

```
  select distinct id, ...
  
  , MAX(publishedat) as post_date
  , MAX(lastmodifiedat) as last_modified
  , MAX(extaction_timestamp) as extraction_date

  from [...]
 where date(extraction_timestamp) = CURRENT_DATE()`
```

This way I would get the most recent extracted record, but it doesn't quite work to tell these two records apart, for instance.

and this is what I got
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq8Iu.png)

I expect the result to return only the first line in yellow, for instance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y7uC.png)

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted

Comment: Please put all your sample data and expected results as formatted markdown tables. That way people don't have to follow unknown links and they can use the text to reproduce your results.

Comment: As it happens I cannot see any of the images you have linked to - PLEASE don't use images of data. Imagine if we proposed a long/complex query in an image as the answer.

Comment: Is the column `ID` a unique identifier (pl remember I cannot see your images). If so it should be easy to identify unwanted rows via `row_number() over(partition by some,columns order by some_timestamp DESC)` so that only the row numbers 1 would be retained and the unwanted rows identified by their `ID`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way could be to select all columns but take the max of the last modified and group by the other columns.

```
select media_id, publication_date, max(last_modified) as last_modified, extraction_date
from table
group by media_id, publication_date, extraction_date
```